# Receiving Import Error: No Module named ***, but has __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I understand that this question has been asked several times but after reading them, and making the suggested fixes, I'm still stumped.

My project structure is as follows:

```
Project
      |
      src
        |
         root - has __init__.py
            |
            nested - has __init__.py
                  |
                  tests - has __init__.py
                  |
                  utilities - has __init__.py
                  |
                  services - has __init__.py
```

I've successfully run a unittest regression class from Eclipse without any issues.

As soon as I attempted to run the same class from the command-line (as other users who will be running the suite do not have access to Eclipse) I receive the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'root'
```

As you can see from above, the module root has an `__init__.py`
All `__init__.py` modules are completely empty.

And assistance would be gratefully received.

Comment: Is `src` on your `sys.path`? Are you running the Python command in that directory or have you explicitly added `src` to your `sys.path` (or `PYTHONPATH` environment variable)?

Comment: @Martijin: I'm attempting to execute from within the '..\tests directory.'
'scr' is not added to 'sys.path' nor 'PYTHONPATH'. I wasn't aware it needed to be, this is the first time trying to execute via the commandline. I'll try adding the directory to the 'PYTHONPATH'

Comment: I won't recommend adding to path. I'd suggest you learn to look at how to setup ``setup.py``, meaning actually create a Python project. That helps you in the long run.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks , I've added in the `sys.path` and everything is good now. I've up voted your comment.
@CppLearner: Reading up on that now. Very useful, up vote for you too, thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try adding a `sys.path.append` to the list of your imports.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Project/src/")
import root
import root.nested.tests
```

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'sys' is not defined` when trying this.

Comment: @CGFoX you need to import sys first, answer modified to reflect this

Comment: This is a hack. It isn't need on Fedora; why would Windows need it?

Comment: What does this actually mean where exactly do I put this code?

Answer (score 22):

Just a note for anyone who arrives at this issue, using what Gus E showed in the accept answer and some further experience I've found the following to be very useful to ensure that I can run my programs from the command-line on my machine or on another colleague's should the need arise.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", ".."))
```

When I execute the 'main' method, which is located in the 'nested' directory, it ensures that the 'src' directory is added to the PYTHONPATH at the time of execution meaning all following imports will not throw an error.

Obviously, you need to adjust the number of ".." arguments to the `os.path.join()` method as determined by the location in your program of where your main method is executed from

Comment: This saved me so much pain. Thank you!

Comment: If this doesn't work try *prepending* to sys.path: `sys.path = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "..")] + sys.path` and it might work then.  I am not sure whether this is caused by my project folder being a folder in my windows 10 Desktop folder.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way to solve this without the path goes like this: consider the following code where inside your folder name 'app' you have 3 files x.py, y.py and an empty **init**.py. So to run x.py you have an import from y such that:

**x.py**

```
from app.y import say_hi
print ("ok x is here")
say_hi()
```

And

**y.py**

```
print ("Im Y")
def say_hi():
    print ("Y says hi")
```

so the folder structure would look like this:

```
testpy
       app
           __init__.py
           x.py
           y.py
```

Solution: in the folder **BEFORE** app do the following:

```
$ python -m app.x
```

**Note: I did not use x.py (simply app.x)**

Result:

```
Nespresso@adhg MINGW64 ~/Desktop/testpy
$ python -m app.x
Im Y
ok x is here
Y says hi
```

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my dozens of hours of python module/name nightmares!

Answer (score 1):

If anybody lands here:

I encountered this error as well. In my case, I used `~/my/path/` at the `path.sys.append(...)`, and the fix was replacing `~` with the explicit path name (you can inquire it if you type `pwd` when you are on linux shell, or use `os.path.expanduser(..)` )

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this so python searches for modules in the current directory is to add it as an environment variable to your .bash_profile / .zshrc / etc. like so:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:."
```